# C++ Socket Connection Error

Tags: c++, sockets, irc

**EDIT**

I've made changes to what I saw below and this is what I have

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

string buffer;
vector<string> ex;
int s;

void recvline ( int s, string* buf ) {
  char in, t;
  while ( 1 ) {
    recv ( s, &in, 1, 0 );
    *buf += in;
    if ( in == 10 ) {
      t = 1; }
    if ( t && in == 13 ) {
      break; }
    }
  }

void push ( int s, string msg ) {
  string o = msg + "\r\n";
  cout << "SENT:", o;
  send ( s, o.c_str(), o.size(), 0 );
  }

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  if ( argc < 3 ) {
    cout << "Insufficient Arguments" << endl;
    exit ( 7 ); }
  s = socket ( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );
  if ( s < 0 )
    exit ( 1 );
  struct hostent h = *gethostbyname ( argv[1] );
  struct sockaddr_in c;
  c.sin_family = AF_INET;
  c.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
  c.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ( h.h_addr_list[0] );
  if ( connect ( s, (struct sockaddr*)&c, sizeof c ) != 0 ) {
      cout << "Unable to connect to network" << endl;
      cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
      exit ( 2 );
  }
  push ( s, "USER LOLwat Lw lol.wat :LOLwat" );
  push ( s, "NICK LOLwat" );
  while ( true ) {
    recvline ( s, &buffer );
    cout << buffer;
    if ( buffer.substr(0,4).c_str() == "PING" )
      push ( s, "PONG " + buffer.substr(6,-2) );
    }
  }
```

And this is the result:

```
[dbdii407@xpcd Desktop]$ g++ ?.cpp -o 4096 - 
[dbdii407@xpcd Desktop]$ ./4096 irc.scrapirc.com 6667 - Unable to connect to network - Network is unreachable
```

Comment: You should check the value of `errno` to see what the actual error was.

Comment: Also, watch your braces - there are a few places where the indentation suggests two lines will execute together, but they don't (eg, right after the unable to connect to network error). I'd recommend using an auto-indenting editor or something.

Comment: and *always* use braces around blocks. C is not Python.

Comment: Can you connect to that port on that irc machine with other tools like telnet or netcat?

Comment: Err, ?.cpp ? ./4096 ? Connecting to IRC? Are you trying to do something fishy?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that this line:

```
c.sin_port = htons(*argv[2]);
```

Is not doing what you think it's doing. `argv[2]` is a string, `*argv[2]` is the first character of the string. So if you passed "4567" as the second command-line argument, then `*argv[2]` will be '4' which has ASCII value 52. That means you'll be attempting to connect to port 52, not "4567" as you would expect.

Change the line to:

```
c.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
```

The [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) function takes a string and converts it to an integer. So "4567" would become 4567.

Also, in general, you should check the value of `errno` when a function call like that fails (it'll usually tell you in [the documentation](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/connect.html) whether errno is set and the possible values it can be set to). That should help to give you some clue in the future.

**Edit**
As others have noted, make sure you pay attention to your braces. It's usually easier if you just *always* use braces around `if`, `while`, and so on. That is, this:

```
if ( connect ( s, (struct sockaddr*)&c, sizeof c ) != 0 )
    cout << "Unable to connect to network" << endl;
    exit ( 2 );
```

Is completely different to this:

```
if ( connect ( s, (struct sockaddr*)&c, sizeof c ) != 0 ) {
    cout << "Unable to connect to network" << endl;
    exit ( 2 );
}
```

Comment: I've edited the file based of what you said. Still have an issue.

Comment: @dbdii407: Do you check the value of `errno`? What does it say?

Comment: Yes, That's the error I got. "Network is unreachable"
And ScrapIRC is my network. It works. There's something weird with this code that I can't figure out.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to completely redo my answer, in part due to the following comment in the [`gethostbyname`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html) manpage:

> The gethostbyname*() and
>   gethostbyaddr*() functions are
>   obsolete. Applications should use
>   [getaddrinfo(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) and getnameinfo(3)
>   instead.

Here is the reworked program ( cleaned up a bit with [bcpp](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/C-C++Beautifier-HOWTO.html) ) based on using `getaddrinfo`.  I would strongly suggest always compiling with the following options:

```
 g++ -Wall -Wextra irc.cpp -o irc
```

This showed up the following bugs in your code:

```
irc.cpp: In function ‘void push(int, std::string)’:
irc.cpp:40: warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect
irc.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
irc.cpp:87: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour
```

I went ahead and fixed the errors.  Also, try and eliminate global variables as much as possible.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

string buffer;
vector<string> ex;

void recvline ( int s, string* buf )
{
    char in, t;
    while ( 1 )
    {
        recv ( s, &in, 1, 0 );
        *buf += in;
        if ( in == 10 )
        {
            t = 1;
        }
        if ( t && in == 13 )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}


void push ( int s, string msg )
{
    string o = msg + "\r\n";
    cout << "SENT:" << o;
    send ( s, o.c_str(), o.size(), 0 );
}


int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc < 3 )
    {
        cout << "Insufficient Arguments" << endl;
        exit ( 7 );
    }

    int s, sfd;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;

    s = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], NULL, &result);
    if (s != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,
                    rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sfd == -1)
            continue;

        if (connect(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1)
            break;                  /* Success */

        close(sfd);
    }

    if (rp == NULL) {               /* No address succeeded */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);           /* No longer needed */

    push ( sfd, "USER LOLwat Lw lol.wat :LOLwat" );
    push ( sfd, "NICK LOLwat" );
    while ( true )
    {
        recvline ( sfd, &buffer );
        cout << buffer;
        if ( buffer.substr(0,4) == "PING" )
            push ( sfd, "PONG " + buffer.substr(6,-2) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with your changes, There's still issues. h->h_addr_list[0] returns B�Z and the inet_addr makes it 4294967295. No clue what that means but just throwing it out there.

Comment: @dbdii407:  Here is the working program.  I suggest getting a good book on C++ programming such as Accelerated C++ by Koenig.